# Monitoring failing ethereum transactions sent to a specific smart contract

Tags: dapps

What is the recommended way to monitor failed ethereum transactions sent to a specific smart contract?

Considering that:
a) Events are not emmitted when a transaction fails 
b) I do not want to include conditions in my smart contract to handle failed transaction. I just want to include some "require"s that can cause a failed transaction.
c) I do not have the hashes of failed transactions
d) I would love a better way than look for all transactions in the blockchain

Comment: `b) I do not want to include conditions in my smart contract to handle failed transaction` - you couldn't even if you wanted to. The failure of a transaction occurs outside the context of your contract, on the transaction-sender's side.

Comment: And generally speaking, every transaction-sender (typically, every dApp) which interacts with your contract, will have to do its own monitoring.

Comment: And since you don't want to use events, the same goes for successful transactions.

Comment: I want events, but they only works when the transaction does not revert. I would like to know what are the transactions that did not succed on the require conditions.

Comment: Transactions that fail are not registered on the blockchain. So your request is not feasible **by definition**. BTW, I've already said that in those 3 comments above.

Comment: I have not understood that before. Anyway, thank you very much for your explanation.

Comment: By the way, according to Etherscan, this failing transaction was included in the block 5389318. https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x184b20bf8c4662aa450276e88070267a59292f8fb019b188218cb6be1f053b43